# How to create your own customize jsonhandler to handle the 'MaxJsonDeserializerMembers

Tags: c#, json

I have this problem of serializing large json and I 
got an exception of 'The JSON request was too large to deserialized'

```
As i've investigate, they used this :

<appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="15000" />
</appSettings>
```

and it really works perfectly fine, but my problem 
is I do not want to 
declare that code in my web.config 
because it will affect my entire system.

Is there any possible way that I can create a jsonhandler and put a customize code that can handle the maxdeserialize members?